# Less expensive way to find pictures for a visual dictionary

Tags: resources

I want to make a picture dictionary, and as it is known, pictures are expensive to buy on the internet. So, if anybody knows a less expensive way to buy pictures for a project, like mine, demanding a large number of pictures. Some people may suggest working with an illustrator, but I think this will take as much money as buying ready made illustrations on the internet. These are only guesses, so correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Comment: The cheapest way to come by images is taking photographs or drawing illustrations yourself.

Comment: I don't think this question is about writing, it's about generating illustrations or photographs.

Comment: @NeilFein But can we see finding illustrations not as a part of writing similar to questions about printing, publishing, agents, etc.?

Comment: @what - My opinion is that this still isn't about writing. That the accepted answer basically says "take your own photographs" supports this; the question and the answer have nothing to do with writing.

Comment: I agree, so let's close.

Comment: Vector graphics resources: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/free-vector-graphic-images-for-commercial-use stock photo resources: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good [visual dictionary](http://www.visualdictionaryonline.com/) has **appealing** illustrations that **clearly communicate the intended meaning**. Good illustrations are what sell a visual dictionaly (or attract web site visitors), and quality usually has its price, because most frequently it is caused by a lengthy and expensive education as an illustrator or photographer.

There are sites such as [deviantART](http://www.deviantart.com), where amateur artists exhibit their work, and sometimes talented visual artists who are willing to work for an apple and an egg can be found there. Those attempts at collaboration that I have wittnessed being formed on this or similar platforms often where either small projects quickly completed, or they failed as soon as one of the partners tired of the continuous demands or left the care of their parents and had to earn their living.

If you want to create a professional product, you will need professional partners, and those cost professional money. The real challenge in a project like yours is not finding illustrators, but finding an investor. This can be a publisher, to whom you submit examples of dictionary entries. Or an investor who you can convince that your project will make money.

While cheapest way to come by images is taking photographs or drawing illustrations yourself, I don't think you will be able to successfully finish such a large project all on your own. It will take a single person years to create a dictionary's worth of illustrations, expecially if they only do it in their spare time (as your question for "no money" seems to imply).

Comment: Thank you. After the 1st answer I thought and searched about it, and found that it may actually take years, and I'm not quite that patient. so I've contacted illustrators and I'm totally willing to pay as much money as they demand :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for pictures (a.k.a. photographs) or illustrations?  Sorry, I am unfamiliar with picture dictionaries, so I don't know what level of art is associated with them.  If you are looking for pictures, the answer is easy...  carry a camera.  I keep a DSLR with a decent zoom lens near me most of the time and carry a cellphone with an 8 megapixel camera with me always.  A day when I don't snap a hundred shots is a day that I didn't get out of bed.  99% are crap.  But I keep everything that is in focus, because someday I might need just that kind of picture.  I take every photo at the highest resolution that the camera will allow, because someday I might need just the lower right corner of a picture, but I still will need it to be usably clear.
Going to the zoo?  Take two extra simms and an extra battery.
Baseball game?  Don't forget to photograph the stands, the lights, the scoreboard.
Digital photography has made massive photo collecting practically free.  Take advantage of it.

Comment: Thank you. Gonna see what I'll do, either learn illustration or photography, and this answer made me consider photography seriously. But there are many things that I won't be able to capture as I don't have them in front of me. Others are very easy to capture since I see them daily.

Comment: Photography and Illustration don't have to be distinct skills.  Adobe's Illustrator has an amazing trace function which can turn high-contrast pictures into scalable line-art.  Their Photoshop program (and many free comparable products like Gimp) can adjust photographic content to look like line art as well.

Comment: As far as having available subject matter, consider joining a photographer's forum with a global reach and make some friends in the areas where your unobtainable subjects are common.  Trading royalty free is uncomomon, but not unheard of.  Just be careful to check the metadata of any photos you get this way to make sure they aren't copyrighted by someone else.  Also, be suspect of any professionally cropped and cleaned photos when trading.  Ask for raw work and clean it up yourself.  I'm in Florida, so if you need any palm trees, beaches, etc., contact me through SE.